# how can we integrate myspace in my website myspace api

Tags: api, myspace

I want open Myspace profile, friendslist and inbox messages from myspace to my website by using Myspace api.

I registered in developer.Myspace and I got applicationkey and consumer key.

I gave callback url also but I am getting 401 error.

Suggestions?

Comment: what language are you writting your code? Do you have a code sample of what you are doing now? Did you check out the api help page?

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means unauthorized so what ever you are doing you are not sending the right credentials.